# Calculating delta in SpriteKit using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am attempting to learn swift by refactoring one of my old games and I need to rewrite my `update` method which calculates a delta time. This code *works* but is ugly. How would I go about *properly* rewriting this?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var lastUpdateTimeInterval: CFTimeInterval?

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

        var delta: CFTimeInterval?
        if let luti = lastUpdateTimeInterval {
            delta = currentTime - luti
        } else {
            delta = currentTime
        }

        lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;

        if (delta > 1.0) {
            delta = minTimeInterval;
            lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
        }

        updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(delta!)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not completely certain refactoring old, existing, *working* code into a language that doesn't yet even allow for access modifiers is the best of ideas, particularly not when the new language can use stuff written in the old language, meaning you can use the new stuff with the old stuff without rewriting any of the new stuff.

Comment: This was more of a way to learn swift. Of course this wouldn't be optimal in a professional environment I know that swift/objc can live together in the same project. The could of course doesn't need to be written in the same manor. How would you go about calculating a delta in a "swift" way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You are inconsistent with the optional semicolons.  It's optional in Swift, but all the example code I've seen from Apple excludes them.  They may be excluding them simply to drive home the point that they're not necessary, but it will probably end up being standard to exclude them.  Either way, you've included them in 3 lines and excluded them in 5.  Consistency is actually more important then what "best practice" says to do, and your code isn't consistent in this regard.
2. In Swift, the parenthesis around `if` statements are optional.  Like the semicolons, you've been inconsistent in this.  You include the parenthesis once and omit them once.  Again, all the example code I've seen from Apple omits them and that will probably become the Swift standard, but again, what's most important is consistency.
3. Perhaps in an effort to force some Swift into your code, you've needlessly declared `delta` as an optional.  There's no possible path through this method which results in `delta` being uninitialized, and that becomes pretty evident when we force unwrap it as we pass it to an argument expecting a non-optional.
4. `updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate()` is probably copied over from a method that looks like this in ObjC: `updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:`, which might be okay.  It's a method called update that takes a variable which describes the `timeSinceLastUpdate`, right?  In Swift, the method *might* be a bit Swift-ier if `timeSinceLastUpdate` is actually the name of the argument: `update(timeSinceLastUpdate:delta)`.  This makes it more clear.  The part outside the parenthesis describes what the method actually does, while the part inside the method describes what sort of arguments to send.

Comment: his parenthesis issue is not really inconsistent,  you can't use parenthesis in an if let statement, so he may be not using parenthesis when testing optionals, but use parenthesis for comparisons.  (There are actually cases where swift forces you to use parenthesis on comparison evaluations)